# how to get only Minutes from "Time" type value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Project in Windows Forms and here I have to Transfer dates from Excel File into DataGridView .

I did it successfully but one of the Cells in Excel is a type of "Time" and there are written times such as `"11:35:19 AM"`, `"12:56:15 PM"`...

In DataGridView it's just copying values but I need to know which Minute or Hour it is. With this Code I can get value of this cell:

```
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value
```

but it gives me `{12/30/1899 12:49:40 PM}`. Here time is correct but it gives me additional date( `12/30/1899` which isn't written in Excel file).

So how to get only Minutes, Hours or Second from this value? In the DataGridView I have to add a new Cell and write there which Hour is. For example:

```
12:19:20 | 12
10:29:45 | 10
11:39:50 | 11
13:49:10 | 13
```

Comment: A bit of formatting goes a long way towards making a question *much* easier to read. Take a moment to familiarize yourself with formatting/markdown on SO.

Comment: `int minutes = ((DateTime)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).Minute;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
dt.hours; // hours
dt.minutes; // minutes
dt.second; // seconds
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in a date, then read the desired values:

```
Date d = New Date(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
int min = d.Minute();
int hour = d.Hour();
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = hour
```

Source: MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

string time = ((DateTime)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value).ToString("hh:mm tt");

This is how your whole time part will be fetched from datetime.